# Blynk & Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, blynk

I followed this guide to get my Raspi and Blynk connected : http://help.blynk.cc/how-to-connect-different-hardware-with-blynk/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-and-blynk . However, when I try to turn on my LED from the app I get the following error:

```
No direct pin operations available.
Maybe you need to install mraa or onoff modules?
```

I have installed the modules and it still doesn’t work

Comment: have you removed old nodejs before installing the new one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJ3ic8C8CcA

Comment: Did you install onoff library? Here is also detailed video tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJ3ic8C8CcA

Answer (score 1):

Better to use blynk library in python it works fine using python instead of running a node server.

Steps for running Blynk on Raspberry Pi (3B/3B+/4B/Zero) :

1. Install blynk library for python using pip3

```
     pip3 install blynklib
     pip3 install gpiozero
```

2. Simple code to turn on LED using virtual pin V4

```py
    import gpiozero

    import blynklib
    
    red = LED(17)
    
    BLYNK_AUTH = '<YourAuthToken>' #insert your Auth Token here
    
    blynk = blynklib.Blynk(BLYNK_AUTH)
    @blynk.handle_event('write V4')
    def write_virtual_pin_handler(pin, value):
        print('Current V1 value: {}'.format(value))
        if(value):
            LED.on()
        else:
            LED.off()
    
    while True:
          blynk.run()
```

Comment: Was this example pulled from a Help Wiki or another site? If so, can you put that link in your answer? Reason being, is so, someone who is working through this, can learn what is calling the function ````write_virtual_pin_handler()```` or details on what each function is calling, or methods being used etc.. or find links to find such details.